# Using nodejs Connect's static server middleware to serve only a subdirectory

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

I'm trying to build a webapp where:

http://example.com/static/x.png  serves x.png as a static file using Connect's static middleware
http://example.com/other_stuff  does other stuff

My directory structure is

```
start_server.coffee
static/
    x.png
```

In start_server.coffee I have:

```
app = connect()
app.use connect.staticCache()
app.use connect.static(__dirname + '/static')

app.use ...middleware that serves the dynamic parts of my app...

app.listen 80
```

When I try http://example.com/static/x.png, the request bypasses the static server and gets routed to the rest of my app.  I stepped through the code in a debugger and it looks like static is trying to lookup static/static/x.png instead of static/x.png.

I was able to get it working by changing connect.static(__dirname + '/static') to connect.static(__dirname), but now it will serve stuff that's not in the static directory which is not good!

What's the cleanest way of doing what I'm trying to do?  I could probably use Express's routing functionality, but I don't particularly want to use Express unless I have to, since the rest of my app handles routing its own way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue is the mismatch between your URL paths and your filesystem layout. There are 2  easy-peasy get-on-with-your-life solutions.

1. Remove "static/" from your URLs. The static middleware will only serve files under the `static` directory but the URLs won't include the word "static".
2. Do this: `mkdir public && mv static public`. Leave the `public` directory empty other than the `static` subdirectory. Now your URLs can stay the same and in your code you need `app.use connect.static(__dirname + '/public')`.

Now this is what the static middleware provides out of the box. The URLs have to map simply to the filesystem. This is why it "just works" and is simple.

If you really want to have `static/` in your URL but not map to a directory underneath your static root, add a middleware before the static middleware that alters req.path to remove the leading "/static", then call `next()` and I think that will trick the static middleware into doing what you want.